# Nodejs fileupload, multer vs express-fileupload, which to use?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

Which library I should use? The only purpose is to upload the files. I want to go with the most optimal library in terms of performance and scalability in terms of large requests. If my project scales up, I will be eventually using CDN services.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are some few things that you have to consider when choosing library in this context.

**Firstly Personal belief:**

- All this things perform the same task so it's all upon preference so whatever that you like to work with go for it do not stress yourself about this and that cause all this is opinion based.

**But to answer your question: which should you  choose?**

- There are 3 libraries that I would recommend that is **Multer**, **Formidable** and **Busboy**

**So which to choose between Multer, Formidable and Busboy**

**1. If you want to store files in memory or disk:**

- Multer is your go to library

**2. If you want to store files in disk:**

-Formidable is your go libray

**3. For high-volume production-grade solution:**

- When you've got a high-volume situation and want the most reliability from your server, the best option is to not store intermediate files on the Node.js server at all. Instead, you want to push the files to a separate file server as soon as you receive them. The file server can be a cloud storage service such as AWS S3 or a database that supports BLOBs.

**Base64 or Multipart?**

**Base64:**

- Base64 is a way to encode binary data into an ASCII character
- formating the data to radix-64 representation.
- If the file uploads that your making are large file uploads then I would for sure with confidence say that **do not use Base64** because it converts whole data and post it to server.

**Multipart:**

- This is faster
- Multipart is a way to upload data to server in the form of part which are in bytes. Multpart/form-data is applied to a form though, so you can send everything in a multi-part form, including "regular" data also.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering the question.

My requirement lies in category 3. I wish to use Imagekit.io for storing the images. Just before uploading to imagekit.io I would need to buffer it somewhere after getting from the frontend. Where should I do it?

Also, what would be the best practice to send the images from frontend?Base64 or multipart? Base64 would resolve the above doubt as well.

Comment: Okay let me edit my answer so to add that second part about base64 and multipart

Comment: Depending on rank :D yes, but I just posted the updated answer on what you want wanted hope this solves your queries and my answer helped you

Comment: so question arises what makes multipart faster